# How to build a jar contains referenced jar libs use maven

Tags: java, maven, build

I want to build a standalone jar program use maven, but the output in target doesn't contains the referenced jar libs, how can I include them in my target?

Comment: Also search for "maven uberjar" and "maven shades plugin"

Answer (score 1):

Use following in pom.xml and build the jar, use assembly plugin

```
<plugins>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>xxxxx</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```